# Sending an array from php and receiving it in android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

Now I have this:

```
$data = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
$data[] = $row;
}
```

Now `$data[0] = array('Joe','Sally','3 5'); $data[1] = array('Joe','alice','30 65');`

Access `$data[0][0] = 'Joe'` or `$data[1][0] = 'Joe'. $data[1][1] = 'alice'`.

then how can i send this 2D array from php and receive it in android using JSONObject or JSONArray?

Comment: You have an sql injection problem ! (Imagine someone having $username `' or 1 -- `). Learn mysqli_* or PDO_* and use parameterized queries ... mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: Not to mention the use of `mysql_` functions ...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$data = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
$data[] = $row;
}
 $json=json_encode(array("userlist" => $data));
        echo $json;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `json_encode()` function to convert your array to json array.In your android development code,you have to add `JSONParser` to extract your information.Try this java class for getting information from PHP using JSON.

```
In PHP
$data = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
$data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: okay thank u but i already have the JSONParser class what i can't do is that i can't receive the 2D array i sent from php in my android activitiy class. how can i do this?

Comment: @user3101219:see my edited version.add json_encode($data).It will work fine.for example if u echo it it will be in the form [{"no":"101","name":"arun"},{"no":"102","name":"Mennakshi"},{"no":"103","name":"Santhosh"}].Just consider the format the example isrelated to my project

Answer (score 0):

User `json_encode($dd)` to show `Json` String

```
$data = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
$data[] = $row;
}
```

echo json_encode($data) ;

Comment: and then how to receive it in android in an array with the same format and then split it by the comma?

Comment: you get Json string array and need to parse this json string.